# Make the blog page a child of another page and rewrite the archive url

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make my WordPress blog page a child of another page and have the url structure reflect that. However, I also have other custom post type archive pages set up that should not be interfered with.

Right now, my blog page is a child of Page Name and the permalink in the backend shows [www.sitename.com/page-name/blog/](http://www.sitename.com/page-name/blog/). However, visiting this page gives me a 404 error even after refreshing the permalink settings.

If I update the post permalink settings to be /page-name/blog/%postname%/, the blog url works, but then my other custom post type archive pages, such as [www.sitename.com/resources/](http://www.sitename.com/resources/), end in a 404.

How can I achieve a nested blog page while not disrupting my custom post type archives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I was able to solve this by updating my `$args` in `register_post_type`. I set `'with_front'` to false in my rewrite parameter for my affected custom post type and just updated my blog post permalink structure to /page-name/blog/%postname%/

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'knowledge-base', 'with_front' => false)
```